# Django: Passing variable from get_context_data() to post()

Tags: python, django

The variable is defined inside `get_context_view()` since it requires an `id` to access correct database object:

```
class FooView(TemplateView):
  def get_context_data(self, id, **kwargs):
    ---
    bar = Bar.objects.get(id=id)
    ---

  def post(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    # how to access bar?
    # should one call Bar.objects.get(id=id) again?
```

What would be the way to pass `bar` variable to `post()`?

Tried to save it as FooView's field and access it via `self.bar`, but this doesn't do the trick. `self.bar` is not seen by `post()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should reverse it. If you need `bar` in `post()`, you need to create it there:

```
class FooView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        bar = self.bar

    def post(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bar = Bar.objects.get(id=id)
        ...
```

`post()` is called before `get_context_data`, that's why `post` doesn't see it if you define it in `get_context_data`.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you know what function runs before post() and has access to passed variables (e.g. `id`)?

Comment: May be you could share a link - in which order do the function (post, get, etc.) get executed. I've already spent some time digging without success.

Comment: Your solution results in Exception Value: 'FooView' object has no attribute 'bar'

Comment: @h3d0 Then you probably have a `get` method that doesn't set `bar`. Use `dispatch` instead, that will set it for every request method. It always starts at `.as_view()`, which calls `disptach` with the same arguments that a function-based view would expect. From there on you can use the source code to follow the flow of methods. I often use [Classy Class-based views](http://ccbv.co.uk/) as a reference, very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late, but I faced this same problem few days ago. However here is my solution.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['foos'] = self.object.filter()
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    foos = self.get_context_data().get('foos')
    # do stuff here
    return context
```

Comment: I get **context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.**

Answer (score 1):

As knbk said, my solution was the dispatch method, there I define the variables that I will use in get_context_data and in post methods, that worked for me as a way to share data
here my example

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    self.some_data = '123'
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyTestCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    print('test get_context_data', self.some_data)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):        
    print('test post', self.some_data)
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[Classy CBV](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/)
I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is defined in your CBV (Class Based View), it can directly be called in your template.

Views.py

```
class SomeRandomView(FormView):
    username = 'SomeValue'
```

Template.html

```
<p>Username is {{view.username}}<p>
```

Sidenote: You can even call the methods in your view class directly within the template file which is after version 1.5 Django if I could recall correctly.