# where to check session in ClassView in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a ListView in my views.py but in this class, I want to check session if the user exit in the session which has been kept in during login

```
 class part_list_view(ListView):
    model = part_list
    context_object_name = 'part_list'
    template_name = 'part_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(part_list_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_list'] = populate_nav_bar()
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `self.request` anywhere in the class based view. In your case `self.request.session`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    session = self.request.session
    # now use session however you want
    context = super(part_list_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['my_list'] = populate_nav_bar()
    return context
```

Comment: but I want to redirect to a certain page when the session does not exist. I guess I would not be able to do

Comment: you can check session in get and post methods of your class based view and then use redirect there

Comment: would not I be overwriting get implementation of the class?

Comment: Implementing get and post for your class based views is pretty standard

Comment: then do i need to to call super()  in get in UpdateView class or other?

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072987/django-passing-variable-from-get-context-data-to-post) might give you some insights